# How to Print a variable in a function in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form, with post="ModelSelector", when submitted, we go through these codes.
Issue I'm facing is, I want to check the value of $_POST, I know it is getting set by calling "isset()".

I just want to Print/alert/pushout the variable $productselection

```
function selectProduct() {       
    // save the post in a variable
    $ProductSelections =  $_POST['ModelSelector'];

    // I want to print $ProductSelection to check its value
    $frmVars['ProductSelections'] = $ProductSelections;
    $frmVars['WindowSize']        = $WindowSize;
    $frmVars['PageNum']  = 1;
    saveFormValues(0,'RunDefMgr', $frmVars);

    // Clear the checkboxes         
    $sel = array();
    deleteRunDef(0,"*","RUN_DEF_EDIT","*");
}


if(isset($_POST['ModelSelector'])) {
    selectProduct();
}
```

I have tried ECHO, for some reason it is not printing the value in HTML.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried, including a print or echo statement and also a snippet of where the $_POST data is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to check the value of $_POST

`$_POST` will be an array.

Use `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` to view its contents.

Comment: It still does not print anything.

Comment: In that case, it is possible that `$_POST` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your form method should be `method="POST"`, You can use the following edit to see if it works , as you have to pass `$_POST (array)`  to the function to use it inside function. function expects an parameter else , `$_POST` does not exists.

And also enable the errors inside your file to check which type of errors you are getting by using : `ini_set('display_errors',1);` or `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

```
function selectProduct($_POST) { // create parameter $_POST which we get from isset condition.
    // save the post in a variable
    $ProductSelections =  $_POST['ModelSelector'];
    print_r($ProductSelections); // print the value.
    // I want to print $ProductSelection to check its value

    $frmVars['ProductSelections'] = $ProductSelections;
    $frmVars['WindowSize']        = $WindowSize;
    $frmVars['PageNum']  = 1;
    saveFormValues(0,'RunDefMgr', $frmVars);

    // Clear the checkboxes         
    $sel = array();
    deleteRunDef(0,"*","RUN_DEF_EDIT","*");
}

if(isset($_POST['ModelSelector'])) {
    selectProduct($_POST); // pass the $_POST array to the selectProduct function.
}
```